# No identifiers are available for signing (Xcode)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store

I've tried to do App Store Submission, it couldn't be completed as the error 
show "No identities are available for signing".

I checked out from the forum and followed step by step, it still can't
fix the problem.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718267/how-do-i-submit-an-app-to-the-app-store-using-xcode-4-3-or-application-loader

Answer (score 0):

Go to developer.apple.com, download the distribution certificate and install that on you mac. After that you will be able to sign your app.

Comment: Thanks rishi ...

I have already downloaded and installed, but still can not solve this problem.

Comment: have you created the certificate on same machine on which you are installing it?

Comment: Yes, I have. But I don't know why can not pass this process.

Have you ever seen this problem?

Comment: Go to iOS Dev Center > iOS Provisioning Portal > Provisioning > Distribution. Check whether your provisioning is still valid or expired. Also recheck the drop down menu in the xcode build setting once more to be sure that you have done all things properly.

Comment: Can you tell me step by step ?

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718267/how-do-i-submit-an-app-to-the-app-store-using-xcode-4-3-or-application-loader

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your Provisioning Profiles have expired.  I already had distribution provisioning profiles created but they had just recently expired.  The error message xCode was giving just said "No identities were available for signing" even though the private/public keys were correctly in the Key Store.  To fix I just did the following:

1. From the iOS Provisioning Portal, select "Provisioning" on the left
2. Under "Provisioning Profiles" select "Distribution" (this is where I could see that the provisioning profiles had expired
3. Click on the expired Provisioning Profile
4. Click "Edit"
5. Select the Certificate you want to use for the Provisioning Profile
6. Click "Generate"
7. Click "Download"
8. Open the file (it should launch xCode and add it to the Organizer)

After this I was able to submit the update to the App Store no problem.  They really need a better error message.